gradio HTML component with <script> in head of gr.Block not working
I am trying to make a gr.HTML component to be clickable in order to set the display:block of a second gr.HTML component. For this I define a <script> block and add it the the head argument of gr.Block. Unfortunately it does not seem to work. For investigating what happens, I added some debug log messages.
Gradio app:
import gradio as gr

head = """
<script>
  console.log("Script loaded!");
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      console.log("DOM loaded!");
      var firstDiv = document.getElementById("first_div");
      var secondDiv = document.getElementById("second_div");
      
      if (firstDiv && secondDiv) {
        firstDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
          console.log("First div clicked!");
          secondDiv.style.display = "block";
        });
      }
  });
</script>
"""

with gr.Blocks(head=head) as demo:
    gr.HTML(
        """
        <div id="first_div" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#eee; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
            Click Me!
        </div>
        """
    )
    gr.HTML(
        """
        <div id="second_div" style="display:none; background-color:#ddd; padding:10px;">
            You clicked, I am visible!
        </div>
        """
    )

demo.launch()

I see the log message "Script loaded!" but not "DOM loaded" nor "First div clicked!".
However, when putting the same into a pure HTML as:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  console.log("Scripts loaded!");
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      console.log("DOM loaded!");
      var firstDiv = document.getElementById("first_div");
      var secondDiv = document.getElementById("second_div");
      
      if (firstDiv && secondDiv) {
        firstDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
          console.log("First div clicked!");
          secondDiv.style.display = "block";
        });
      }
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="first_div" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#eee; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
  Click Me!
</div>
<div id="second_div" style="display:none; background-color:#ddd; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
  You clicked, I am visible
</div>

</body>
</html>

it works as expected.
Also changing the concept from "DOMContentLoaded" to window.onload as:
head = """
<script>
  console.log("Script loaded!");
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log("Window onload fired!");
    const element = document.getElementById("first_div");
    if (element) {
      console.log("Element found!");
    } else {
      console.log("Element not found!");
    };
  };
</script>
"""

or to document.readyState as:
head = """
<script>
  console.log("Script loaded!");
  if (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") {
    console.log("Document ready")
    const element = document.getElementById("first_div");
    if (element) {
      console.log("Element found immediately!");
    } else {
      console.log("Element not found immediately!");
    };
  }
</script>
"""

does not help.
What am I missing? Can anybody help, that would absolutely be awesome!

Maybe this can help: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/gradio-html-component-with-javascript-code-dont-work/37316/2. It states that you can load JS code also with demo.load(_js="...your JS..."). Plus, instead of using addEventListener, you can try do directly define a function and use it with the onclick attribute in the DOM element. More on this approach also here: https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/3446#issuecomment-1477564504

Thanks @SherlockBourne for your ultra quick reply, I tried this as well but it unfortunately won't even show the first console.log message.

I never used Gradio before, but after looking a bit at the docs I found out a potentially good solution, although with a slightly different approach. The steps are:

Set as head the definition of the function that will be run when the first div is clicked.
Define the HTML elements setting the onclick attribute to the first div, which will be calling the function defined in step 1.

After running this snippet, it worked for me:
import gradio as gr

head = """
<script>
  function clickHandler() {
    console.log("First div clicked!");
    var secondDiv = document.getElementById("second_div");
    secondDiv.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
"""

with gr.Blocks(head=head) as demo:
    gr.HTML(
        """
        <div id="first_div" onclick="clickHandler()" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#eee; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
            Click Me!
        </div>
        """
    )
    gr.HTML(
        """
        <div id="second_div" style="display:none; background-color:#ddd; padding:10px;">
            You clicked, I am visible!
        </div>
        """
    )

demo.launch()

Hope it works for you, too!

Heeeei, this works for me, thank you so much!!!!!

You are welcome! Please, remember to upvote and/or mark the answer as solution so it gains visibility for other users as well :)

done (for upvoting I need more reputation but answer is marked as a solution). Thanks again for your answer

Thank you very much! And, again, you are welcome :)
